# All paths of a tree

Tags: python, recursion, path

How could one go on about listing all paths within a tree using recursion?

I call this in the shell:

```
t = Tree(1)
t2 = Tree(2)
t7 = Tree(7), t2.children = [t7]
t5 = Tree(5)
t9 = Tree(9)
t8 = Tree(8)
t5.children = [t8, t9]
t.children = [t5, t2]
```

Basically I made that tree to looks like this:

```
     1
   /   \
   2    5
   |    /\
   7   9  8
```

I want to return the following paths within a list:

```
[[1, 2, 7], [1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 8]]
```

Overall I can make the list, it's just finding a way to get the specific path that I'm struggling to do! Would appreciate any help!

Comment: what is `Tree?` If you implemented it then post it's code. If it's publicly available library then provide a link.

Comment: @VinodSharma I think a reasonable guess is this: `class Tree:
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v
        self.children = []`

Comment: @Shashank I agree with you. But I think, it's best to be clear.

Comment: Are you only looking for paths with length = to the longest path length? Or maybe root->leaf paths?  Because the edges `[1,2]`, `[2,7]`, `[1,5]`, `[5,9]`, `[5,8]` are all paths as well.

Comment: Yes, Sashank is correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your class structure is similar to the following, then you can use recursion to get all the paths.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = []


def get_paths(t, paths=None, current_path=None):
    if paths is None:
        paths = []
    if current_path is None:
        current_path = []

    current_path.append(t.value)
    if len(t.children) == 0:
        paths.append(current_path)
    else:
        for child in t.children:
            get_paths(child, paths, list(current_path))
    return paths


t = Tree(1)
t2 = Tree(2)
t7 = Tree(7)
t2.children = [t7]
t5 = Tree(5)
t9 = Tree(9)
t8 = Tree(8)
t5.children = [t9, t8]
t.children = [t2, t5]

print get_paths(t)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 7], [1, 5, 9], [1, 5, 8]]
```

@Shashank thanks for guessing the possible structure of the `Tree`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way of doing it using completely immutable objects, tuples, and no arguments besides the tree itself. Instead of using a mutable list to store state, we simply pass tuple-wrapped values upwards along the chain. `get_paths` is bound to return a tuple of tuples every time.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.children = ()


def get_paths(t):
    if t.children:
        return tuple((t.value,) + path 
            for child in t.children 
                for path in get_paths(child))
    else:
        return ((t.value,),)


t = Tree(1)
t2 = Tree(2)
t3 = Tree(3)
t4 = Tree(4)
t5 = Tree(5)
t6 = Tree(6)
t7 = Tree(7)
t8 = Tree(8)
t9 = Tree(9)
t.children = (t2, t5)
t2.children = (t7,)
t5.children = (t9, t8)
t9.children = (t6,t3,t4)

print(get_paths(t))
```

Of course, there's nothing wrong with passing around a mutable list to store state, but I believe this solution is a bit more elegant and functional.

To convert it to a list of lists structure, you can simply do:

```
paths = [list(path) for path in get_paths(t)]
```

Or just replace all the tuples in the function with lists and you're good to go!